# `git status` prints way too much whitespace before each file

Tags: git, git-status

I'm sorry if this problem is phrased somewhat strange, but I am kind of lost here and don't even know how to google this issue.

Running `git status` prints the usual list of modified files, but it adds so much whitespace before each file that only the first character is printed on the current line...
This happens regardless of my terminal/window width in both powershell and wsl.
[image: screenshot to show the problem]

Resizing the window:
[image]

Now running `git status` again in the resized window again increases the whitespace such that only a single character is printed before wrapping...

I am puzzled, as this happened at random without me knowingly changing any kind of config.
Plus, `git branch` etc works just fine.

Comment: can you try (in WSL at least) `git status | cat` ? If the output is "fixed", it could be an issue with how your terminal handles colored output

Comment: Are you using windows CMD?

Comment: The `git status` command outputs tab (`\t`, ASCII code 9) characters. A terminal emulator *should* treat such characters as "move to the next mod-8 column" (columns 1, 9, 17, 25, ...). Yours appears to treat the first tab as "move to column 70" or some such. You could find various workarounds, but it seems like the *best* fix is to whap the software into following the normal standards.

Comment: If all else fails, though, try sending `git status` output through the `expand` command, which expands tabs. (It may get a bit confused by the colorization stuff though—chances are that, as @LeGEC suggested, this is what's confusing your terminal emulator when you resize a window.)

Comment: @LeGEC `git status | cat` does not "fix" the issue, so should not be a color problem

Comment: @torek `git status | expand` indeed "fixes" the output, though it does not resolve the root cause...
Any idea where this problem originates from?

Comment: @Gileos : ok, and what about tabs, as torek suggested ? run `echo $'\tfoobar'` (from bash in WSL)

Comment: @LeGEC Indeed, `echo $'\tfoobar'` shows the same erroneous behavior as `git status` and as I said above, the expand solution at least corrects the output, but is not resolving the root cause

Comment: I don't know offhand. Terminal emulators, especially fancy ones, tend to have a lot of settings. Investigate whatever terminal emulator is installed on your system and how to set its settings, including tab-stop settings.

Comment: @torek okay, thank you for the insights. Actually I did not install any terminal emulator myself, so it should be Windows' default one...
I hope someone who comes around this question knows the answer as my google search results mostly link to unrelated issues with tab autocompletion etc :(

Comment: Googling for "windows terminal tabulation width" : found this link https://superuser.com/questions/1503681/wsl-tab-character-takes-up-an-entire-line . At least, the OP had the same problem as you.

Comment: @LeGEC thanks, it at least shows a fix for WSL. However, still no idea where the problem can be fixed permanently